# How to Keep the ExpandableListView Checkboxes Checked States?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, expandablelistview, android-checkbox

Currently I can check/uncheck the checkboxes by groupPosition and childPosition, and it's working fine.  I save the groupPosition and childPosition to the SQLite Database.

When I added the delete option, my checkbox checked states are off/messed up.

For example, I have the following:

Group1,

Child1, Child2, Child3

I check all 3 of them and save the checked positions to the SQLite Database.
The checked positions would be 0,0 and 0,1 and 0,2 in the Database.

After I deleted Child1,

Child2 becomes position 0, Child3 becomes position 1 which would mess up the checked states.

I am trying to find a way to save the group name and child name instead of the positions to the SQLite Database, then load those names in Oncrete method.

MainActivity:

```
if(category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected) {

        category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected = false;    
        try{
            MySQLITE_DATABASE.deleteRows(groupPosition, childPosition);
           }            
        catch (Exception e) {}

 } 
  else 
 {
    category_array.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected = true;                 
    MySQLITE_DATABASE.addRow(groupPosition, childPosition);
 }
```

Adapter code:

```
private List<Category> mGroupCollection;

if(mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition).subcategory_array.get(childPosition).selected) {
    childHolder.checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox_checked);

} else {
    childHolder.checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkbox_unchecked);
}
```

Date Holder Classes:

```
public class Category {
public String category_name = null;
public String cat_SelectedChildCount_name;
public ArrayList<SubCategory> subcategory_array = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
}

//==============================

public class SubCategory {
public String subcategory_name = null;
public boolean selected = false;
}
```

I want to save the group name and child name instead of positions to the SQLite Database and then load them in OnCreate method.

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
 String Group_Name = category_array.get(Integer.parseInt(groupPosition)).category_name;             
 String Child_Name = category_array.get(Integer.parseInt(groupPosition)).
                                                subcategory_array.get(Integer.parseInt(childPosition)).subcategory_name;



if(category_array.get(Group_Name).subcategory_array.get(Child_Name).selected) {
   category_array.get(Group_Name).subcategory_array.get(Child_Name).selected = false;
   MySQLITE_DATABASE.DeleteRow(Group_Name, Child_Name); 
}

else {               
    category_array.get(Group_Name).subcategory_array.get(Child_Name).selected = true;
    MySQLITE_DATABASE.AddRow(Group_Name, Child_Name); 
    }
```

I know that I need to change the code in the adapater, data holder classes, and mainactivity in order to make it work, but I am out of ideas.  I have been thinking and thinking, but nothing works...

Can someone please please guide me on this?

I am sorry for the long code.

Thank you and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the following if it suit's your requirement.

If you want to use the position strictly (May be there is no unique option)

- Keep the DB design like

---

```
| id | parent_position | child_position |
```

---

Assume you have N childs. If you delete a child (Suppose it's 0). do this

- Update all the child's with (child_position = child_position - 1) whose position is greater than 
  the deleted child of the parent. So the position remains unchanged.

Personally i would suggest don't use the `position` if a delete option is there. Option that i found, But don't know your use case

- If you are loading the list from the database use the database `primarykey` as the key to save it in the `SQLite database` on selection/unselection. In this case you don't want to know the parent position as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  You mentioned don't use the position if a delete option is there.  How can I achieve this?  In my adapter, it requires both groupPosition and childPosition in order for it to have the checkbox checked or unchecked. As far as, child_position - 1, I have thought about it, but then I thought it would be slow performance when more than 1 childPositions are deleted.  I very appreciate it.

Comment: Yes. It would a bit. In your adapter you can `setTag` the details you want to associate with each row of list. Try to use that

Comment: I have no clue how to start with setTag and getTag.  I will just give you a check for mentioning about child_position = child_position - 1.  I go with this idea for now until I learn now more about Android for better performance later.  Thanks a lot for helping my friend.

Comment: You are welcome :). `SetTag `is nothing a method where you can keep any data related to the corresponding `view`. Try it out, it will help you in your day's ahead.